# Interpretation K-Means clustering with PCA - Python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

I have implemented a K-Means clustering on a dataset in which I have reduced the dimensionality to 2 features with PCA.

[Clustering analysis plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn8F6.png)

Now I am wondering how to interprete this analysis since there is any reference on which are the variables on the axis.
Given that doubt, I am also wondering if it is a good practice implementg a K-Means on a resized dataset with PCA.

How can I interprete this kind of clustering?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.stats import anova

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
df = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)
model = smf.ols(formula='np.log(mpg) ~ np.log(wt)', data=mtcars).fit()
print(anova.anova_lm(model))
print(anova.anova_lm(model).F["np.log(wt)"])



import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df.fillna(0, inplace = True)

x = df.iloc[:,2:]

wcss = []
for i in range(1,11):
   model = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = "k-means++")
   model.fit(x)
   wcss.append(model.inertia_)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(range(1,11), wcss)
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()

pca = PCA(2)
data = pca.fit_transform(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
var = np.round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_*100, decimals = 1)
lbls = [str(x) for x in range(1,len(var)+1)]
plt.bar(x=range(1,len(var)+1), height = var, tick_label = lbls)
plt.show()


centers = np.array(model.cluster_centers_)
model = KMeans(n_clusters = 6, init = "k-means++")
label = model.fit_predict(data)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
uniq = np.unique(label)
for i in uniq:
   plt.scatter(data[label == i , 0] , data[label == i , 1] , label = i)
plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], marker="x", color='k')
#This is done to find the centroid for each clusters.
plt.legend()
plt.show()

df['label'] = label
df
```

Final result:

[image]

Etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Sorry if this is a little off topic, but you may also want to consider using Feature Importance with the Random forest algo. That will tell you which independent features have the most influence on the dependent feature. As I understand it, PCA will not tell you which features are PCA1 & PCA2. See the link below for more info.